# Can you have a dust storm in a vacuum?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vacuum, atmospheric-science

Is it possible for a dust storm to form in a vacuum at normal $g$, where the only particles interacting with each other are specs of dust, or do you need a more traditional fluid base?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by a dust storm since the term normally means suspension of dust grains in a gas. For example it is possible to have an electrostatically stabilised dust suspension in a vacuum.

Comment: @JohnRennie I think that's the heart of the question. When you think of the meteorological event known as a dust storm, with waves of interacting gases carrying billowing clouds of dirt, sand and other particulate matter, I'm asking if this effect is possible without the dust being suspended in a gas, but rather with the dust itself acting to suspend itself, and interactions between particulate matter replacing interactions between gas molecules.

Comment: You can have dust in a vacuum. The dust can interact. The dust can act in a manner that is fluid-like.  Is that a storm ?  I think that's a question of choice of definition or opinion.

Comment: There is "dust" in space (i.e., small silicate particles ranging in size from kilometers down to sub-nanometer), but that kind of begs the question of whether it is still a vacuum.